# UserDir and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I'm creating a website with the Yii Framework and trying to hide the entry script. Everything works fine in my local (MAMP) server, but when I go to deploy it on to my Uni's Linux server I get a problem. I imagine it's related to `UserDir`, but I'm not sure.

When I request: `http://website/username/site/research`
I get:

```
The requested URL /~home/username/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.
```

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

I don't where to start investigating the problem. Could it be with `UserDir`? Or with my `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`? Or with the configuration of `Yii`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Next, trouble can be because of apache configuration. Option "AllowOverride" should be set as "All":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/example.com/frontend/www

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    <Directory /home/sites/example.com/frontend/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use `RewriteBase /` I get  `/~index.php`. Any idea what causes that tilde to be there? I know our personal websites are accessible also from `http://website/~username/`, which redirects to `http://website/username/`, but I don't have access to the apache config.